# Persian localization for Ag-Grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, farsi

I want to develop a persian web app using ag-grid but the content of the ag-grid is completely English.

How can I localize ag-grid to persian(farsi) language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the [localeText] property of ag-grid component to your own localization object like AG_GRID_LOCALE_FA that i will explain.
here a simple example about usage of the component...

```
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 100%; height: 500px"
    class="ag-theme-alpine" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" 
    [rowData]="rowData$ | async" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"

    [localeText]="AG_GRID_LOCALE_FA"
</ag-grid-angular >
```

the AG_GRID_LOCALE_FA variable is an object hard coded in ts file of the component that contain persian translated labels for every key.

here is the persian locale object.

```
AG_GRID_LOCALE_FA = {
    selectAll: '(انتخاب همه)',
    selectAllSearchResults: '(انتخاب همه نتایج جستجو)',
    searchOoo: 'جستجو...',
    blank: 'خالی',
    notBlank: 'پُر',
    blanks: '(جای خالی)',
    noMatches: 'بدون منطبق',
    filterOoo: 'فیلتر...',
    equals: 'برابر',
    notEqual: 'نه برابر',
    empty: 'یکی را انتخاب کن',
    lessThan: 'کمتر از',
    greaterThan: 'بزرگتر از',
    lessThanOrEqual: 'کمتر یا مساوی',
    greaterThanOrEqual: 'بزرگتر یا مساوی',
    inRange: 'در محدوده',
    inRangeStart: 'به',
    inRangeEnd: 'از',
    contains: 'حاوی',
    notContains: 'شامل نشود',
    startsWith: 'شروع با',
    endsWith: 'مختوم به',
    dateFormatOoo: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    andCondition: 'و',
    orCondition: 'یا',
    applyFilter: 'اعمال',
    resetFilter: 'بازنشانی',
    clearFilter: 'پاک کردن',
    cancelFilter: 'لغو',
    textFilter: 'فیلتر متن',
    numberFilter: 'فیلتر عدد',
    dateFilter: 'فیلتر تاریخ',
    setFilter: 'تنظیم فیلتر',
    columns: 'ستون ها',
    filters: 'فیلترها',
    pivotMode: 'حالت محوری',
    groups: 'گروه های ردیف',
    rowGroupColumnsEmptyMessage: 'برای تنظیم گروه های ردیف اینجا را بکشید',
    values: 'ارزش ها',
    valueColumnsEmptyMessage: 'برای جمع آوری اینجا را بکشید',
    pivots: 'برچسب های ستون',
    pivotColumnsEmptyMessage: 'برای تنظیم برچسب های ستون به اینجا بکشید',
    group: 'گروه',
    loadingOoo: 'در حال بارگیری...',
    noRowsToShow: 'هیچ ردیفی برای نمایش وجود ندارد',
    enabled: 'فعال',
    pinColumn: 'سنجاق کردن ستون',
    pinLeft: 'سنجاق کردن به چپ',
    pinRight: 'سنجاق کردن به راست',
    noPin: 'بدون پین',
    valueAggregation: 'تجمیع مقادیر',
    autosizeThiscolumn: 'اندازه خودکار این ستون',
    autosizeAllColumns: 'اندازه خودکار همه ستون‌ها',
    groupBy: 'گروه‌بندی بر اساس',
    ungroupBy: 'لغو گروه بندی بر اساس',
    resetColumns: 'بازنشانی ستون ها',
    expandAll: 'گسترش همه',
    collapseAll: 'بستن همه',
    copy: 'کپی',
    ctrlC: 'Ctrl+C',
    copyWithHeaders: 'کپی با سر ستون',
    paste: 'چسباندن',
    ctrlV: 'Ctrl+V',
    export: 'خروجی',
    csvExport: 'CSV خروجی',
    excelExport: 'خروجی اکسل (.xlsx)',
    excelXmlExport: 'خروجی اکسل (.xml)',
    sum: 'جمع',
    min: 'دقیقه',
    max: 'حداکثر',
    none: 'هیچ',
    count: 'شمار',
    avg: 'متوسط',
    filteredRows: 'فیلتر شده',
    selectedRows: 'انتخاب شده',
    totalRows: 'همه ردیف ها',
    totalAndFilteredRows: 'ردیف',
    more: 'بیشتر',
    to: 'به',
    of: 'از',
    page: 'صفحه',
    nextPage: 'صفحه بعدی',
    lastPage: 'آخرین صفحه',
    firstPage: 'صفحه اول',
    previousPage: 'صفحه قبلی',
    pivotChartAndPivotMode: 'نمودار محوری و حالت محوری',
    pivotChart: 'نمودار محوری',
    chartRange: 'محدوده نمودار',
    columnChart: 'ستونی',
    groupedColumn: 'گروه بندی شده',
    stackedBarColumn: 'انباشته شده',
    normalizedColumn: '100% انباشته شده',
    barChart: 'میله ای',
    groupedBar: 'گروه بندی شده ',
    stackedBar: 'انباشته شده',
    normalizedBar: '100% انباشته شده',
    pieChart: 'پای',
    pie: 'پای',
    doughnut: 'دونات',
    line: 'خط',
    xyChart: 'XY (اسکتر)',
    scatter: 'اسکتر',
    bubble: 'حباب',
    areaChart: 'منطقه',
    area: 'منطقه',
    stackedArea: 'انباشته شده',
    normalizedArea: '100% انباشته شده',
    histogramChart: 'هیستوگرام',
    pivotChartTitle: 'نمودار محوری',
    rangeChartTitle: 'نمودار محدوده',
    settings: 'تنظیمات',
    data: 'داده',
    format: 'فرمت',
    categories: 'دسته ها',
    defaultCategory: '(هیچ)',
    series: 'سریال',
    xyValues: 'XY مقادیر',
    paired: 'حالت جفت',
    axis: 'محور',
    navigator: 'هدایتگر',
    color: 'رنگ',
    thickness: 'ضخامت',
    xType: 'نوع X',
    automatic: 'اتوماتیک',
    category: 'دسته',
    number: 'شماره',
    time: 'زمان',
    xRotation: 'X چرخش',
    yRotation: 'Y چرخش',
    ticks: 'کنه',
    width: 'عرض',
    height: 'ارتفاع',
    length: 'طول',
    padding: 'فاصله',
    spacing: 'فاصله گذاری',
    chart: 'نمودار',
    title: 'عنوان',
    titlePlaceholder: 'عنوان نمودار - برای ویرایش دوبار کلیک کنید',
    background: 'پس زمینه',
    font: 'فونت',
    top: 'بالا',
    right: 'درست',
    bottom: 'پایین',
    left: 'چپ',
    labels: 'برچسب ها',
    size: 'اندازه',
    minSize: 'حداقل اندازه',
    maxSize: 'حداکثر اندازه',
    legend: 'افسانه',
    position: 'مقام',
    markerSize: 'اندازه نشانگر',
    markerStroke: 'حرکت نشانگر',
    markerPadding: 'پدینگ نشانگر',
    itemSpacing: 'فاصله مورد',
    itemPaddingX: 'پدینگ ایتم X',
    itemPaddingY: 'پدینگ ایتم Y',
    layoutHorizontalSpacing: 'فاصله افقی',
    layoutVerticalSpacing: 'فاصله عمودی',
    strokeWidth: 'عرض ضربه',
    offset: 'افست',
    offsets: 'افست ها',
    tooltips: 'نکات ابزار',
    callout: 'فراخوانی',
    markers: 'نشانگرها',
    shadow: 'سایه',
    blur: 'تار',
    xOffset: 'X افست',
    yOffset: 'Y افست',
    lineWidth: 'عرض خط',
    normal: 'عادی',
    bold: 'پررنگ',
    italic: 'مورب',
    boldItalic: 'پررنگ مورب',
    predefined: 'از پیش تعریف شده',
    fillOpacity: 'تاری انباشته',
    strokeOpacity: 'تاری خط',
    histogramBinCount: 'تعداد جعبه',
    columnGroup: 'ستون',
    barGroup: 'میله',
    pieGroup: 'پای',
    lineGroup: 'خط',
    scatterGroup: 'XY (اسکتر)',
    areaGroup: 'منطقه',
    histogramGroup: 'هیستوگرام',
    groupedColumnTooltip: 'گروه بندی شده',
    stackedColumnTooltip: 'انباشته شده',
    normalizedColumnTooltip: '100% انباشته شده',
    groupedBarTooltip: 'گروه بندی شده',
    stackedBarTooltip: 'انباشته شده',
    normalizedBarTooltip: '100% انباشته شده',
    pieTooltip: 'پای',
    doughnutTooltip: 'دونات',
    lineTooltip: 'Line',
    groupedAreaTooltip: 'Area',
    stackedAreaTooltip: 'انباشته شده',
    normalizedAreaTooltip: '100% انباشته شده',
    scatterTooltip: 'اسکتر',
    bubbleTooltip: 'حباب',
    histogramTooltip: 'هیستوگرام',
    noDataToChart: 'داده ای برای ترسیم در دسترس نیست.',
    pivotChartRequiresPivotMode:
      'نمودار محوری نیاز به فعال کردن حالت محوری دارد.',
    chartSettingsToolbarTooltip: 'منو',
    chartLinkToolbarTooltip: 'پیوند با جدول',
    chartUnlinkToolbarTooltip: 'لغو پیوند از جدول',
    chartDownloadToolbarTooltip: 'دانلود نمودار',
    ariaHidden: 'پنهان',
    ariaVisible: 'مرئی',
    ariaChecked: 'بررسی',
    ariaUnchecked: 'چک نشده',
    ariaIndeterminate: 'نامعین',
    ariaColumnSelectAll: 'تغییر وضعیت انتخاب همه ستون ها',
    ariaInputEditor: 'ویرایشگر ورودی',
    ariaDateFilterInput: 'ورودی فیلتر تاریخ',
    ariaFilterInput: 'ورودی فیلتر',
    ariaFilterColumnsInput: 'ورودی ستون های فیلتر',
    ariaFilterValue: 'مقدار فیلتر',
    ariaFilterFromValue: 'فیلتر از مقدار',
    ariaFilterToValue: 'فیلتر به مقدار',
    ariaFilteringOperator: 'اپراتور فیلتر کردن',
    ariaColumnToggleVisibility: 'نمایش تغییر ستون',
    ariaColumnGroupToggleVisibility: 'تغییر نمای گروه ستون',
    ariaRowSelect: 'برای انتخاب این ردیف SPACE را فشار دهید',
    ariaRowDeselect: 'برای لغو انتخاب این سطر, SPACE را فشار دهید',
    ariaRowToggleSelection: 'برای جابجایی انتخاب ردیف, Space را فشار دهید',
    ariaRowSelectAll: 'برای جابجایی انتخاب همه ردیف ها, Space را فشار دهید',
    ariaSearch: 'جستجو',
    ariaSearchFilterValues: 'مقادیر فیلتر جستجو',
  };
```

for more information and probable updates take a look at my github repo:
[Ag-grid persian localization guide](https://github.com/AliTarani/Ag-grid-locale-fa)